# Safari Warning: Possible Phishing Site - Send http request to an IFRAME ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, httprequest, phishing

I am trying to perform action in `iframe` that not visible to the user ( width 1 height 1 ).
The following action(Javascript) is related to Webcam API:

```
function down(){
ifrResult.location = "http://"+user+":"+password+"@"+ip+":"+port+"/decoder_control.cgi?command=2&onestep=5";
}
function up(){
ifrResult.location = "http://"+user+":"+password+"@"+ip+":"+port+"/decoder_control.cgi?command=0&onestep=5";
}
```

As you can see the iframe id is ifrResult.

**Problem:**
On Chrome browser the action is performed without any issues but on Safari I get an error:
[image: Warning Message]

Does anyone faced with this issue before? suggestions are welcomed, Thanks!

**EDIT**
For the avoidance of doubt, this is legal operation its just a wrapper for Webcam interface.

Comment: Is this even legal??!!

Comment: The problem is not about iframe or javascript. Safari issues this warning for all websites with http basic auth.